# autoreconf fails with 'Can't exec "libtoolize"'

Tags: debian, autoconf

I wanted to learn about autotools, so I just started watching some tutorials on YouTube.

I made a folder named `hello` and then made a `configure.ac` file:

```
AC_INIT([hello],[.01])
AC_OUTPUT
```

I saved it and then ran `autoreconf -i`. Obviously, this didn't work the first time because it was not installed. Then I installed `autoconf` by the command `sudo apt-get install autoconf2.13`.

Now after this I again ran `autoreconf -i`, but now I am getting the error as show below:

```
Can't exec "libtoolize": No such file or directory at /usr/bin/autoreconf2.50 line 196.
Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at /usr/bin/autoreconf2.50 line 196.
```

Comment: I just checked my hello folder , it created the `configure` and the `autom4te.cache` but still , when running `autoreconf -i` it is showing these two lines of error , will there be any problems in future , what are these errors ?

Comment: Instead of au→reconf−iautoreconf -i if i do au→conf−iautoconf -i , then it is not showing any error . what are the difference b/w `autoreconf` and `autoconf` command

Comment: When you have an error message which refers to a program that appears to be missing, like libtoolize here, you can try `apt-file search filename` and replace filename with what you have and it'll tell you what package you need to install.

Comment: @illuminE that sure is handy information will remember that for future

Comment: sudo apt-get install build-essential libtool worked for me - I would up vote it but I don't have the reputation to do so

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You should do `sudo apt-get install build-essential libtool`

Comment: Just tried it , but stil showing the same error

Comment: @TrafalgarLaw Could you also try out `sudo apt-get install libtool`. I'm not sure if it's included in build-essential.

Comment: Thanks man , you were right it worked :) ! `libtool` is not in `build-essential`

Comment: specially `apt-get install libtool` for the binary `libtoolize`

Answer (score 5):

Try this..

`sudo apt-get install automake autoconf libtool
autoreconf -i`

This worked for me.